# Database Schema Design Adive

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am using laravel 5.1 with sentinel package. 
I would like to create online accreditional structure, which will has institutions and certificateholders. 
But i didnt imagine how do i do this kind structure:

A institution officer would be registered to the site, then will describe institutions profile. But this institutions might be individual (personal) or institutional.

A certificate holder would be registered by insitution officer to its own company. Then assigns certificate to holder.
But certificate holder might be personal or an institution...

I really didnt imagine this kind. 
Thanks for advise.

I think there would be 4 tables:

```
Institutions | PersonelCertificateHolders | InstituionalCertHolders | Users
```

And there must be polymorphic relation between these 4 tables and models must store in Users table. Right?
Is there any idea out there?

Comment: But now you do? I guess you got the tense wrong there ... Have you tried to design an ER or alike? Pretty helpful.

Comment: what is er? entitity relationships?

Comment: Exactely. It often helps trying to write it down / make a scratch to spot misconceptions etc

Comment: I think there will be two tables with users table, one is certificateholders and second is institutions. i think this is polymorphic relations? because certificateholders and institutions are have user in users table?

Comment: Can you give an example what the different parts are / what they do and how they interact with each other / belong together?